# Expressão regular no delphi 7

Tags: delphi, regex, delphi-7

Caros, sou iniciante em programação no Delphi 7, e também em expressões regulares.

Delphi 7 porque na empresa em que estou trabalhando, por outros motivos, eles têm que usar o Delphi 7.

Preciso trabalhar com expressões regulares, alguém conhece alguma maneira. Pelo que li, tem uma biblioteca pra isso, alguém poderia me dar um norte?

Comment: Por acaso vocês utilizam o Jedi JCL no projeto? pois ele tem a classe TJclRegEx para trabalhar com expressão regular.
Utilizamos ela aqui na empresa e atende muito bem!

Answer (score 3):

Para as versões anteriores ao XE, existe alternativas como [**TRegExpr**](http://regexpstudio.com/TRegExpr/TRegExpr.html) que é gratuita.

- [**Perguntas frequentes**](http://regexpstudio.com/TRegExpr/Help/faq.html)
- [**Sintaxe**](http://regexpstudio.com/TRegExpr/Help/RegExp_Syntax.html)
- [**Métodos e propriedades**](http://regexpstudio.com/tregexpr/help/tregexpr_interface.html)

Nas versões mais recentes do Delphi há [suporte nativo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_the_RTL_%28Run-Time_Library%29), a unidade (*unit*) a ser usada é [`System.RegularExpressions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.RegularExpressions).

Um [**exemplo**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/TRegExReplace_%28Delphi%29) simples de substituição:

```
function TForm1.ReplaceCC(const Match: TMatch): string;
begin
  i := i + 1;
  Result := InttoStr(i);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  regex: TRegEx;
  input: string;
  myEval: TMatchEvaluator;
begin
  i := 0;
  input := Edit1.Text;
  regex.Create('cc');
  myEval := ReplaceCC;
  Edit2.Text := regex.Replace(input, myEval);
end;
```

Há também a biblioteca de código aberto [`System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx) que implementa [expressões regulares compatível com Perl](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html).

Comment: Obrigado colega. O que eu estou procurando fazer, é o seguinte: quero criar na minha aplicação, um identador de SQL, semelhante à esse: www.sqlformat.org. Não sei se é necessário usar regex, pois, tentei fazer algumas coisas já, e quase deu certo. O que eu fiz, foi assim: coloquei 2 memos e 1 botão no form. Na action do botão, eu pego o conteúdo do memo do sql que não está identado, e jogo em uma stringlist, e separo as palavras pelo espaço, algo assim:

Comment: Parte := TStringList.Create;
  Parte.Delimiter := ' ';
  Parte.DelimitedText := query;
  Parte.Clear;
  ExtractStrings([' '], [], PChar(query), Parte);

Então, se eu atribuir o conteúdo do sql formatado do memo 2 o conteúdo do Parte.text, todas as palavras são separadas e ficam embaixo uma da outra. Então, o que eu fiz foi tratar as palavras reservadas com o case. Mas ainda assim, tenho outras dificuldades, entretanto, não sei se esta lógica é a mais indicada, o que você acha?

Comment: @ÉderPereira Acho que esse é o caminho mesmo. Para ter uma ideia melhor, olhe o código do [**JEDI Code Format**](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/) ele não é um identador de SQL, mas dá para ter uma noção. Sobre a resposta tem algo que eu possa melhorar nela?

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado. Na verdade, estou com uma dificuldade, pois ele está gerando algumas linhas duplicadas, e não sei como retirá-las, se quiser, lhe envio por email, não sei se é conveniente postar aqui. Por mim tudo bem.

Comment: @ÉderPereira Bom, não tenho o Delphi para testar agora, se você quiser [criar uma nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) e postar o código que tem até o momento, talvez mais pessoas possam ajudar. Se tiver algo a mais que eu possa colocar na resposta a respeito da *regex*, pode dizer, se possível marque a resposta como aceita.